# URL redirecting messed up (WordPress & Opencart)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo, opencart

I need your help with something that has me flummoxed.

I have WordPress installed in domain root (www.csillamvilag.com) and OpenCart in a subfolder (www.csillamvilag.com/shop/).

Both installations are multilingual (WP is multilingual via WPML).

Deployed OpenCart SEO URLs in core program, and Multilingual SEO URL Bundle plugin for OpenCart.

The multilingual plugin for Opencart creates beautiful URLs like www.csillamvilag.com/shop/hu/ingyen-e-book which mostly work very well.

However, the OpenCart root for Hungarian language (our primary language) does not.
www.csillamvilag.com/shop/hu/ redirects me to www.csillamvilag.com/rolunk/husegprogram/ which is a WordPress page.

I should note at this point that:
 * English shop root works fine www.csillamvilag.com/shop/en/
 * If I change the slug of husegprogram to something that doesn't start with hu, then I get a 404.
 * RewriteBase is correct in the OC .htaccess and there is no mention of hu in WP .htaccess

I'm totally at a loss here, and would greatly appreciate some help.

Using
 * WordPress 3.5.1
 * OpenCart 1.5.4.1 with vQmod 2.3.0
(just to clarify, there is no integration between WordPress and OpenCart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out for me, the problem was that there was a physical folder /shop/hu/

I deleted that and now the URL www.csillamvilag.com/shop/hu/ is being properly handled by the Multilingual SEO URL plugin for OpenCart.

(this means WordPress was hijacking the URL because while checking for physical files/folders it was finding one and then trying to handle it the best it could)